# How to show D3 Graph with Year and month on x-axis across different years

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have created a D3 chart with year column as a number and have worked. But now we need to add the month and so I have added the month for one year as `201701,201702,201703,201704......201712` then the code is working fine as expected.

But when I just include `201611` (Nov 2016) for years list then `2017` year months all overlap.(I understand that it is taking as a number and that's why the number the difference between `201701` and `201611`)

This is the screenshot:
[image: plunker]

I have tried with the changing that x-axis field as date field as now it is parsing as a number but was unsuccessful.

My Code is in :
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ekE5UNfOKlqOthfeHHtl?p=preview)

The binding of Graph is present in the mainscript.js and how to change x-axis as date fields

Comment: I can't load up your example on my phone, but I think it's something to do with scaling the X-axis, using scalepoint/scaleband to set each number to a discrete point on the x-axis, therefore ignoring all numbers between 201611 and 201701. https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md%23band-scales&hl=en-IN#a.band-scales

Comment: @OliverHouston Thanks for the idea but here I need to show only the Dates present on the data sheet. So now that dates are parsing as a number that's why this much distortion in the graph. I am not able to change this number to date and show it there.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the numbers to a date, it's more to do with positioning. Assume your graph area is 240 pixels wide and you have 12 months to show. You want to place each month 20 pixels apart. Then you set you're scalePoints to 12 in 240 and assign each number to a scalePoint. Using the index of the data objects rather than the data itself. It adds a layer of complexity, but it's still fast.

Comment: @OliverHouston Yes if I know how many months I can do that but here I cant know how many months. like 201612, 201711 like that dataset will be always different no. of values

Comment: You can use .length to find the number of months in your array. Something like var N=graph.months.length or appropriate to your data structure, then use N to set up the scale points.

Comment: @OliverHouston Showing scalePoint() is not a function. it would be great if you try in that pluker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161293/discussion-between-oliver-houston-and-charan-tej).

Comment: I am using d3.v3 so scalepoint is showing not a function. I am already using scale.linear please look at the plunker